# Python class example texas holdem efficiency

Tags: python, class, poker

Hi am working on a simple texas holdem dealing simulator. I am new to python and was hoping to get some advice on my use of classes here. I feel like I am not using them as efficiently as possible, especially when dealing out the player cards. Specifically I feel like the `def deal(self, n_players)` could be simplified instead of using playercard1 and playercard2, and deleting the items from the "deck"? Here is the code:

```
from random import shuffle

class TexasHoldem:
    #create deck
    def __init__(self):
    values = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    suites = ['Heart', 'Spade', 'Club', 'Diamond']
    self.deck = [j + " " + i for j in values for i in suites]

    #shuffle deck
    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.deck)

    #deal for players
    def deal(self, n_players):
        count = 0
        #card 1 list (will be shuffled, delt 'around the table' as if a real stack)
        playercard1 = list()
        while count < n_players:
            card1 = self.deck[count]
            playercard1.append(card1)
            count += 1

        #remove cards from deck that were delt 
        for i in playercard1:
            self.deck.remove(i)

         count = 0
         #card 2 list 
         playercard2 = list() 
         while count < n_players:
             card2 = self.deck[count]
             playercard2.append(card2)
             count += 1

         #remove cards from deck delt for 2nd card
         for i in playercard2:
             self.deck.remove(i)

        #merge cards of playercard1 and playercard2 into set     
        self.playerhand = zip(playercard1, playercard2)

    #define the flop    
    def flop(self):
        #burn a card
        del self.deck[0]
        #lay down three
        self.flopcards = self.deck[0:3]
        #delete flop from deck
        for i in self.flopcards:
            self.deck.remove(i)

    #same as flop for turn and river        
    def turn(self):
        del self.deck[0]
        self.turncard = self.deck[0:1]

        for i in self.turncard:   
            self.deck.remove(i)

    def river(self):
        del self.deck[0]
        self.rivercard = self.deck[0:1]

        for i in self.rivercard:
            self.deck.remove(i)

#create instance of Cards class            
c = TexasHoldem()
#shuffle for this instance
c.shuffle()

#deal for n players
c.deal(9)

print 'Player Hands:'
for i in c.playerhand:
    print i

#flop
c.flop()
print 'Flop:'
print c.flopcards

#turn
c.turn()
print 'Turn:'
print c.turncard

#river
print 'River:'
c.river()
print c.rivercard
```

Comment: I think you want http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.   This seems off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, I will post there!

Answer (score 1):

Some quick comments:

- `flop`, `turn` and `river` are all doing almost the same. You could have a method that returns a list of cards from the top of your deck
- For that method, instead of first extracting the card and then removing it, you can do it at the same time calling `list.pop`. Then you will never make a mistake to delete the wrong amount
- To be even safer, you could have different classes that represent the different states in the game. That makes sure whoever is calling your methods won't call them in wrong order. You would then have a `ShuffledDeck` `DealtDeck`, etc and each method would return an instance of the next class. Taking advantage of multiple return values, the code would look like the following.

  ```
  deck = new Deck() # fresh deck
  deck = deck.shuffle() # a shuffled deck
  deck, hand = deck.deal() # a deck without dealt cards
  ```